# How can I create disposable NSManagedObject objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

I like using Core Data object modeling, because it gives me generated code and behavior that I like.

For example, relationships with the inverse object being updated automatically.

However, for most of my projects I don't need persistent storage. Specifically, I'd like not to save all the objects I created every time I save the context.

What would be a good way to do this?

I thought of using an extra context for disposable objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried creating an in-memory persistent store? When you create a managed object instance, you can assign it to this in-memory store, which will not persist any data to disk, and also is reset on the next launch of your app.

Another way to go is to create a second Managed Object Context, and make sure you never save it.

Comment: I ended up creating a second ManagedObjectContext. It's a bit tricky keeping the two separate, but seems to do the job.